# Passing variable number of arguments to function in a perl script

Tags: perl

I am working with a perl program that is going to have a variable number of arguments/parameters.  Basically, my perl program is run by doing something along the lines of:

```
perl progam.pl hello, I am a simple statement
```

The program does some odds and ends, but that's not important to what I'm trying to ask here. What I want to do with the `"hello, I am a simple statement"` part is pass that to the echo function within the perl script.

Though it should work with any number of arguments/parameters.

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

When you execute the shell command

```
perl progam.pl hello, I am a simple statement
```

It launches `perl` and passes these 7 arguments to it:

- `progam.pl`
- `hello,`
- `I`
- `am`
- `a`
- `simple`
- `statement`

`perl`, in turn, will execute `progam.pl` after populating `@ARGV` with the other arguments. As such, you could do

```
system("echo", join(" ", @ARGV));
```

Or course, that's exactly what `echo` does, so you could simply do

```
system("echo", @ARGV);
```

Or did you mean `print` when you said `echo` (cause it doesn't make much sense to execute `echo`)?

```
print(join(" ", @ARGV), "\n");
```

Note that it would be better if you passed the text as a single argument.

```
perl progam.pl 'hello, I am a simple statement'
```

Your approach will fail, for example, if some of the words had more than one space between them.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that it will fail because the shell will remove the spaces, not because of anything that Perl does.